# Populate multiple selectbox data inside a Marionette.compositeview

Tags: marionette

In merionette.js , I have more than two selectbox inside form . If I take the form as a compositeview , How can I populate data in those selectbox . Is there any way . If not what I can do ?

Comment: Using a CompositeView for a form, what is your model, what is your collection?

Answer (score 1):

CompositeView is not meant to populate select boxes. It serves the purpose of rendering collections. The classic example would be a tree or, commonly, Order and OrderDetails. For populating select boxes asynchronously, create a Collection and use the onRender of a view. An example is following.

```
var AddressView = new Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    onRender: function() {

        var self = this;
        var statuses = new Backbone.Marionette.Collection.extend({url:"/order/statuses", model: Backbone.Model.extend({}) });
        statuses.fetch().done(function(){
            var html = '';
            statuses.each(function(statusModel){
                html += '<option value="'+statusModel.get('id')+'">'+statusModel.get('name')+'</option>';
            });
            self.ui.selectBox.html(html);
        });

    }

});
```